# Can't access window.variable outside function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, global

I use the function createpolygon to create an array of variables:

```
    <html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="67px" TextMode="MultiLine" 
        Width="325px"></asp:TextBox>

       <button onclick="createpolygon();" style="height: 52px; width: 95px">crea polygoni</button>
         <button onclick="createpolygon2();" style="height: 52px; width: 95px">crea polygoni2</button>

  </div> 
<script>



//----------------------------------------------------
function createpolygon(){

   window["arrayoflines"] = document.getElementById("TextBox2").value.split("-");
for(var i = 0;i < window.arrayoflines.length - 1;i++){
alert(window.arrayoflines[i]);

}
}

function createpolygon2(){
alert(arrayoflines[2]);
}

</script>

    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

and it works.
When I try to get the value of window.arrayofvalue[2] in another function, for example:

```
function createpolygon2(){
 alert(arrayofvalue[2]);
}
```

It doesn't work

```
  function createpolygon2(){
 alert(window.arrayofvalue[2]);
}
```

doesn't work as well.

Comment: Why so many bad votes. What is wrong?

Comment: Did you `console.log(arrayofvalue)` just to see whats in there?

Comment: [I didn't downvote] The reason is likely the fact that you have not provided enough information for us to help you. The code you posted, as it is, should work. You need to provide a minimal code example that **reproduces the issue** so that we can see what's wrong. Please post the HTML you have (as little as needed to reproduce), and enough JS so that we can see how these functions are called and when.

Comment: But the function createpolygon works. I can't get the variables in the sencond function createpolygon2. Not much more code: two button. Button 1 call createpolygon. Button2 call createpolygon2.

Comment: @DanieleMartarelli Like blex said, [that code should work](https://jsfiddle.net/8hcu5Lmy/). Please provide a [mcve] for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Here is the entire code.

Comment: That's better. I think the problem here is that clicking on the button submits the form and reloads the page. You could try to [prevent the default behavior](https://jsfiddle.net/rmu7owdn/) (check out what I added in the JS part)

Comment: Thank you very much Blex. Thanks for the code.